# How to make Thunar mount a drive with exec option enabled?

Tags: mount, executable, thunar

I have a Linux executable placed on a FAT32 flashdrive. But, whenever I clicked the exe on Thunar, it doesn't get started. Instead, Thunar opens up the "Open With" dialog. From searching, I can conclude that Thunar uses the `noexec` option when mounting my device. I can actually run the exe, but I need to mount the drive manually with `sudo mount /dev/sdx folder/ -o uid=my_uid` and I think its rather inconvenient. How can I make Thunar uses the `exec` option?

NOTE:
I have searched for solutions and tried fstab but it doesn't work:

```
# /etc/fstab
...
# I want the solutions to work with all drive, so I didn't use `UUID=` or `LABEL=`
/dev/sdXX /run/media/ vfat defaults,exec 0 0
```

Instead there were an error when booting complaining that it can't mount the said drive because it can't literally mount `/dev/sdXX`.